# como usar la autenticacion de laravel sin las contraseñas encriptadas?

Tags: php, laravel, login

la autenticación de Laravel que viene por defecto me funciona bien en la tabla user, donde las contraseñas estan encriptadas, el detalle es que uso una tabla donde no usa el password encriptado.

ya se que es una mala idea tener las contraseñas sin encriptar pero es una tabla que ya esta echa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedo modificar los registros de la base da datos ya que hay otros modulos que están funcionando con la contraseña sin encriptar, a si que la solución a mi problema fue crear un un accesor que hashee la contraseña y a si poder compara la contraseña ya hasheada.

```
public function getContraseniaAttribute($contra)
{
     if( \Hash::needsRehash($contra) )
     {
         $value = \Hash::make($contra);
     }
     return  $contra;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo actualiza las contraseñas... puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
User::get()->map(function ($user) {
    return $user->update(['password' => \Hash::make($user['password'])]);
});
```